# How to convert time stored in varchar2 to 24-hour format in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, time, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have time as HH:MI:SS AM/PM stored in a varchar2 column in a table. How can I convert this to 24-hour format?

Comment: seriously, if you have a date in a varchar2, isn''t it time to store it in a datetime2 column?

Comment: Out of my hands. I don't have the access. I am more annoyed than you are but this is what I have to work with.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To convert to a `DATE`:

```
to_date(<text field>, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
```

To convert to another string:

```
to_char(to_date(<date field>, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

e.g. (with `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` set to `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`):

```
select to_date('09/08/2013 5:13:07 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),
  to_char(to_date('09/08/2013 5:13:07 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),
    'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
from dual;

TO_DATE('09/08/2013 TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('09
------------------- -------------------
2013-08-09 17:13:07 09/08/2013 17:13:07
```

If you *only* have the time portion:

```
select to_date('5:13:07 PM', 'HH:MI:SS AM'),
  to_char(to_date('5:13:07 PM', 'HH:MI:SS AM'), 'HH24:MI:SS')
from dual;

TO_DATE('5:13:07PM' TO_CHAR(
------------------- --------
2013-08-01 17:13:07 17:13:07
```

Notice that if you don't provide the date part of the value it defaults to the first day of the current month (mentioned in [the documentation for datetime literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062); but if you only have the time you probably want to keep it as a string anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `2013-08-01 17:13:07 17:13:07`
Notice that if you don't provide the date part of the value it defaults to the first day of the current month (mentioned in the documentation for datetime literals), but if you only have the time you probably want to keep it as a string anyway.